# read MSSQL tables in disk order

Tags: sql-server, performance, io, disk

[How to take advantage of Disk IO queueing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309286/how-to-take-advantage-of-disk-io-queueing)
I need to do exactly this but on Microsoft SQL server tables.
I have a database with +100 tables.I need to read every record of every table.
Any suggestions?  Is it worth writing code doing benchmarks and debugging for a few seconds?
It would be really nice if i could tell where each table resides on disk.
And because somebody will ask: Yes, This is a bottleneck in my program.

Answer (score 4):

That other answer is irrelevant for SQL Server. SQL Server does IO it's own way.

Some pointers though:

- Ensure every table has a clustered index
- You have regular index maintenance
- Ensure you have good disks underneath (RAID etc)
- Use Enterprise edition for read ahead functionality if it is that critical
- Ensure you have plenty of RAM

What does this mean?

- If you want to use SQL Server Express on a single workstation disk, then don't bother. You can't optimise this
- Having clustered indexes and index maintenance ensures that data is mostly contiguous on disk (subject to subsequent data changes)
- A proxy for how long this will take would be to run DBCC CHECKDB on all table. Or ALTER INDEX rebuild. Both will require all data to be read from disk for all tables

Comment: +1, "then don't bother. You can't optimise this". yeah. The only answer i didn't want to see:)

Comment: @Behrooz: 100MB should fit in memory, so you just have to get it there. On a good IO subsystem, this should be very quick